# How to launch a VM inside a VMWare player with a shell script?

Tags: virtualization, vmware-player

I am forced to use VMware Player instead of VirtualBox, so I wonder what is the answer for the same [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/490420/how-to-launch-a-script-inside-a-vm-from-the-host)  (similar to this [one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/500966/shell-script-to-run-vm)) as this but in the context of a VMWare player ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible, although somewhat complicated as the documentation for performing this is a little obscure to me.

First, you must ensure that the VMWare tools are installed and running on your guest machine.  In Linux, this does mean compiling them, and in Windows, they can be installed from the disk.

Secondly, you must have the `vmrun` utility.  This *might* be included with vmware plaer, if not, you will need to find and download it from vmware.com

An example command that I used to test the feature is this:

`vmrun  -T ws -gu username -gp password runProgramInGuest ./vmware/Ubuntu/Ubuntu.vmx -noWait  /usr/bin/X11/xclock -display :0`

As you can see from the picture below, this was successful

[image]

Comment: You have a solution for everything :) Thank you very much Charles.

Comment: Not always!  This one took a lot of digging to get operating correctly with linux guest - but I'm running several VMs on both VMWare and VirtualBox, and sometimes I need to add to my bag of tricks!