# Script that opens a program in a VM

Tags: microsoft-office

So I recently began using ubuntu and I'd like to use the MS Office Suite. I have a full suite through the office for education program, so I'd like to be able to use it. I was wondering if it's possible for me to write a script called "Microsoft Word" that when I run it, it opens Word in a windows 10 VM. I'm using KVM for the vm. Is this possible?

Also, is this the best way to be able to use MS Office on Ubuntu? Or is there another, easier way? FYI, I don't have an installation cd, id have to download the office programs online through either another windows computer or the vm.

Thanks

Comment: I don't think that's possible.  You could start a virtual machine that starts Word automatically, or you could keep Word running and just suspend Windows or pause the VM when you don't need it.

Comment: I think it is possible, probably in multiple ways. Have a look here.
http://askubuntu.com/questions/490420/how-to-launch-a-script-inside-a-vm-from-the-host
   the paid version of Wine, "Crossover" offers decent MS office support.